# min-height not working in Chrome, Safari

Tags: html, css, web

> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k6ZjN/)

I've got the following HTML

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">

        </div>
        <div id="content">

        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and this CSS

```
        html{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #container{
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 25px;
            min-width: 960px;
            min-height: 600px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000;
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000;
            -khtml-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #header, #content, #footer{
            width: 90%; 
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #header{    
            height: 55%;
            background: #ccc;
        }

        #content{
            height: 40%;
            background: Yellow;
        }

        #footer{
            height: 5%;
            background: Green;
        }
```

So, I have a min-height set on the container. When I resize the page, I'd expect the contents to shrink till they reach the min-height and then scrollbars should appear after that point and the contents shouldn't shrink anymore. This is exactly what's happening in IE(10) and Firefox but when I run this in Safari/Chrome the contents keep on shrinking as if there is no min-height. Since this is happening in Safari/Chrome both of which use the webkit engine, I am inclined to believe it is a webkit problem. Anyone got any ideas?

**Update**. Apparently it's a version problem. I was using Chrome 23 but this works on 29. Still doesn't work on Safari though (Safari Windows 5.1.7). It would also be nice to know why it didn't work on the (not-so)older version. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Try removing the height styling from html and body

Comment: @Itay That messes up other stuff. See this http://jsfiddle.net/k6ZjN/4/

Comment: @TahirYasin There's a fiddle link at the top.

Comment: Your fiddle works as expected here. Which Chrome version are you testing on?

Comment: @user123_456 Why not?

Comment: Works as expected on Chrome Version 29.0.1547.62 m

Comment: @MrLister Chrome 23.0.0.2585 and Safari 5.1.7

Comment: Then the good news seems to be that it's a bug in Chrome that was fixed recently. Are you in a position to update your Chrome? (Judging by your version number of Safari, you can't update that one. Oh well.)

Comment: @MrLister Actually I was using Torch which was built on v23. But I'll have think about compatibility. I still believe it's a webkit thing since it happened in safari and chrome only.